# How to find max of one column of all child in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a chart like picture , that store it in table with `KID , ParentID` .
how can i get max MR for all child under parent.

**example** : for Node C ---->  max ( MR(D) , MR(E) , MR(F) )

How can find Max(MR) for all child of node?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @a TABLE
(
    KID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ParentID INT,
    MR INT
)

INSERT INTO @a (KID, ParentID, MR)
VALUES
    (1, 0, 3), (2, 1, 1), (3, 1, 3),
    (4, 3, 3), (5, 3, 5), (6, 5, 3)

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @a
    WHERE ParentID = 3

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.*
    FROM cte t1
    JOIN @a t2 ON t1.ParentID = t2.KID
)
SELECT MAX(MR) 
FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

result -

```
5
```

Comment: Thanks. now, how can i update a column (MaxMR) and put this max to MaxMR column ?

Comment: please provide your table schema and expected result. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use over clause

```
SELECT 
  ParentID,
  MAX(MR) OVER(PARTITION BY ParentID) 
FROM
  Table
```